# How to center the contents inside this container without sacrificing width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How to center the contents inside this container without sacrificing the width. I could decrease width and do margin: 0 auto but thats not what I want.

Currently the form doesn't look in the middle it looks aligned left. From the first character to the end of the image the form should appear to be at the center of the page that is what I am trying to do.
https://jsfiddle.net/yj4zh297/

```
<!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <!-- Required meta tags -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

            <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <title>Print Form</title>
            <style type="text/css">
              .line{
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
              }
              .clear {
                clear: both;
              }
              .row {
                margin: 0;
              }

              .container-fluid div {
                margin-bottom: 3px;
              }
            </style>
          </head>
          <body>

            <div class="container-fluid" style="background: grey;">

                <div class="col-sm-6 float-right">
                  <!--.img-fluid . max-width: 100%; and height: auto; are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent elemen-->
                  <figure style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px;">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/rC8Btb0.jpg" class="img-fluid"  alt="image">
                  </figure>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 float-left">
                    Form Number: <span class="line">21129012</span><br>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    Hostel: <span class="line">(Yes / No)</span><br>
                </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12">
              Course Applying For: <span class="line"> BSC Informatics and robotics</span><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12">
              Full Name (IN BLOCK LETTERS): <span class="line"> DLKLKDJ LKDJDKDJD</span><br>
            </div>

             <div class="col-sm-12">
              Gender: <span class="line"> Male</span><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12">
              Phone Number: <span class="line"> 3838443322</span><br>
            </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12">
              Email: <span class="line"> 3838443322</span><br>
            </div>
         </div> <!--end of container-->
            <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
            <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a width:100%; max-width: 800px; to the container-fluid.
And add margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;